# unable to get embedded scroll view to scroll

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uinavigationitem

I'm using storyboard to create a details view. I have a `UITabViewController`, which then goes to a `UITableViewController`, then to my `MessageDetailsViewController`, which is a subclass of `UIViewController`. My controller's main view also has a `UIScrollView` subview, which contains all of my elements as subviews.

In storyboard, my layout has the navigation bar at the top, and the tab bar at the bottom.

I resized the `UIScrollView` to fill the full parent view, going behind the tab bar and navigation bar.

I set up some static subviews in the scroll view, then I add a bunch of extra labels to the scroll view dynamically in a for loop. In the simulator, the labels are showing up where I'd expect them to, but I cannot get the view to scroll. I'm setting the scroll view's content size with:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, y);
```

Where y is the `frame.origin.y + frame.size.height + VerticalBuffer` of the final item (it shows up as 1200+ in my log message, so it's getting calculated properly).

What am I missing to make it scroll properly?

Comment: Have you checked self.scrollView.scrollEnabled is set to yes?

Comment: @Gizmoloon Yes. It is set.

Comment: In what method are you setting the contentSize?

Comment: @mattyohe In the controller's `viewDidLoad`.